# Migrate and initialize database not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a Laravel project **new**. I want to migrate the database and initialize the database. so inside **new**  project I have

```
vendor/bin(folders)/phinx.php(file)
```

I want to migrate the database and initialize tables
I tried:

> vendor/bin/phinx migrate(not working)

```
/var/www/html/new/vendor/bin $ cd phinx seed:run
```

but

> bash: cd: phinx: Not a directory

I am new to laravel, how can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to migrate some tables of a package ?

Comment: Is phinx a package you installed? Other than that there's [documentation on migration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations) available, basically you run `php artisan migrate` to run migrations. If you have a 3rd party package with migrations you'd first need to `php artisan vendor:publish` to publish those migrations to the `database/migrations` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this
  for create database table

```
/var/www/html/new $ vendor/bin/phinx migrate(no need of cd)

and intialize tables

  /var/www/html/new $ vendor/bin/phinx seed:run
```